# How to start `systemd --user` instance server system

Tags: systemd

I have a server system with CentOS 7 here. It is running systemd but it is not starting per-user systemd:

```
➜  ~ systemctl --user
Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory
```

This prevents me from using user units for some daemons.

I have searched a bit and it appears that `systemd --user` can be started by [`pam_systemd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_systemd.8.html). But that appears to start the `systemd --user` instance only upon logging in. Am I correct?

So, should I instead create a system unit which will start `systemd --user` for my specific user with `User=` setting? Or is there any other convenient way how to start `systemd --user` for some users?

Answer (score 1):

You'd enable automatic starting of the user session using `loginctl enable-linger yourusername`. This enables you to do user daemons using user unit files.

I do this on servers, where I have a user with user unit files bringing up podman pods, i.e., networks, volumes and containers for some web application. It's pretty neat.